# How to pass X'221A argument to int main(int argc,char *argv[]) in C

Tags: c, arguments, argv

Hey coders does anyone know how am I supposed to pass argument with "special" character? I get an error:

> sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string

So this is how I call my program trying to put `X'221A` into my `argv`:

```
./program X'221A
```

Comment: try `./program "X'221A"`. As the error indicates, this is dependent on your shell though, and has nothing to do with your program. This question is best for another exchange, perhaps [Super User](https://superuser.com/)

Comment: still getting the same error :(

Comment: try `./program X\'221A`. If that doesn't work, I'm out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'` is a special character for the bourne shell. You need to escape it.

```
./program X\'221A
```

The following will also work:

```
./program "X'221A"
```